# Converting base64 to image is giving bitmap data

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Iam trying to convert base64 to image and passing image data to jquery.while dislaying in data table it is not displaying image. because to jQuery image is not going

```
 public Image Base64StringToImage(string base64String)
    {
        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

        ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
        var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
        return image;
    }
```

this is my base 64 to image conversion.the following is my jquery.

```
  { 'data': 'EmpPhoto',
  "render": function (Data, type, row, meta) {
  var imgsrc = 'data:image/png;base64,' + Data;
  return '<img src="/media/' + imgsrc + '" height="100px" width="100px">';
    }
 },
```

But image is not displaying in screen because i am getting bitmap from base64 to image conversion .please help me out.

Comment: Please show a [mre] of your problem. There's no way of telling what's wrong right now

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below HTML snippet to render an image from the base64 string of an image.

```html
<!-- jpeg encoded base64 image string -->
<img src"data:image/jpeg;base64,jpeg_image_base64_encoded_string"/>

<!-- png encoded base64 image string -->
<img src"data:image/png;base64,png_image_base64_encoded_string"/>
```